# HelloSign how to use different texts for email subject and document name in email body

Tags: php, hellosign-api

I'm using HelloSign to send a template already in HelloSign and using PHP to send it. I want to choose different email subject and a different document name in the email body. How can I use different texts for both of these?
Currently the **setSubject()** in the signature request sets the email subject as well as the document name shown in the email body under **DOCUMENT** sub heading. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the email is set using the setSubject() method. To change the title, you can use the setTitle() method. More information on the subject and title parameters can be found in the [Send With Template endpoint documentation](https://app.hellosign.com/api/reference#send_with_template).